# Deserialize a JSON string integer to an Enum in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core API and my users have a role, like so

```cs
class User
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    public string Email {get; set;}

    public Role Role {get; set;}
}

enum Role : byte
{
    User = 0,
    Administrator = 1
}
```

The problem now is, that my user `CreateOrUpdate` endpoint is getting this JSON data

```json
{
    "id": "2abe50d6-4c81-4ace-ad95-c8182d4384a3",
    "email": "someEmail@example.org",
    "role": "0"
}
```

Here's the problematic endpoint declaration

```cs
public User CreateOrUpdate([FromBody] User user)
{
    // ...
}
```

And it fails to deserialize this, and as such returns `HTTP 400 Bad Request`. But, if I remove the quotation marks around the `0` of the `role` property, it works like a charm.

So, how do I get ASP.NET Core to deserialize the `"0"` to a `0` and as such to the enum variant `User`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [How to customize property names and values with System.Text.Json - Enum as string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties#enums-as-strings).

By default, System.Text.Json convert enum from integer, but in you case "0" is a string. You need specify a converter to convert enum from string like :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o =>
    {
        o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to write your own converter. Depending, if you're using either [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) or [Microsoft.Json.Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) the implementation are more or less the same, but you have to take care to use the classes and properties out of the right namespace and do not mix them.

Depending on your usage you can take a look into the original code of the `StringEnumConverter` either at [Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/EnumConverter.cs) or [Newtonsoft](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/StringEnumConverter.cs) and write your own based on that.

In your class you can then apply this converter by using the corresponding attribute to the specific attribute.